Water surface mapping sentinel-1 otsu-threshold not working
For my graduation project, I need to model and compute the water surface area of different reservoirs located in Vietnam. The temporal scale should be 10-days so the sentinel-1 is taken as baseline for the extraction of the water surface area. Collecting the needed images as well as filtering background scatter out goes well. Although defining a threshold is not working properly.
Below is the code I use to determine the surface area of water for the Ban Chat dam in Vietnam. The Otsu algorithm gives a threshold value that is too high (towards positive), causing the water surface area to be vastly overestimated. How can I modify this code to determine a sufficient Otsu threshold?
var dt = table;

// Function to convert from dB to linear
function toNatural(img) {
  return ee.Image(10.0).pow(img.select(0).divide(10.0));
}

// Otsu threshold calculation function
var otsu = function(histogram) {
  var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
  var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
  var size = means.length().get([0]);
  var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var mean = sum.divide(total);
  
  var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
  
  // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
  var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
    var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        .divide(aCount);
    var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
    var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
    return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
           bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
  });
  
  print("otsu_function", ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array(bss), 0, means));
  
  // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
  return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

// Function to convert to dB
function toDB(img) {
  return ee.Image(img).log10().multiply(10.0);
}

// Applying a Refined Lee Speckle filter
function RefinedLee(img) {
  // Function body (implementation of Refined Lee Speckle filter)
}

for (var j = 2016; j <= 2023; j++) {

  //Define the times of interest
  var monthStartDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(j, 05, 01);
  var monthEndDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(j, 05, 15);
  
  //Collect the Sentinel-1 images for the specified time period
  var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(
      ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'),
      ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING')));
  
  var before = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(monthStartDate, monthEndDate)).filterBounds(dt);
  
  var before_image = before.select('VH').mosaic().clip(dt);
  
  // Apply Refined Lee Speckle filter to the image
  var before_filtered = ee.Image(toDB(RefinedLee(toNatural(before_image))));
  
  // Plot histogram
  var histogram = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
    image: before_filtered,
    region: dt,
    scale: 10,
    maxBuckets: 1000
  });
  print("histogram", histogram);
    
  // Compute histogram
  var histogramDict = before_filtered.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(255)
        .combine('mean', null, true)
        .combine('variance', null, true), 
    geometry: dt,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  print("histogramDics", histogramDict)
  
  
  //Define the otsu-threshold for every specific image
  var threshold = otsu(histogramDict.get('sum_histogram'));
  
   // Define when a certain cell is seen as water, based on the reflectance threshold
  var water_threshold = threshold
  var water = before_filtered.lt(water_threshold);
  var water_mask = water.updateMask(water.eq(1));
  
  print('Total District Area (km2)', dt.geometry().area().divide(1000000));
  
  // Remove isolated pixels
  // connectedPixelCount is Zoom dependent, so visual result will vary
  var connectedPixelThreshold = 25;
  var connections = water_mask.connectedPixelCount(25);
  var disconnectedAreas = connections.lt(connectedPixelThreshold);
  var disconnectedAreasMask = disconnectedAreas.not();
  var water_mask = water_mask.updateMask(disconnectedAreasMask);
  
  //Center map to AOI
  Map.centerObject(dt, 14);
  
  // Define the surface area
  var stats = water_mask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: dt,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13,
    tileScale: 16
  });
  
  // Print the surface area
  //print(stats);
  var water_area = ee.Number(stats.get('sum')).divide(1000000);
  
  print(j, water_area);
}


//############################
// Speckle Filtering Functions
//############################

// Function to convert from d
function toNatural(img) {
  return ee.Image(10.0).pow(img.select(0).divide(10.0));
}

//Function to convert to dB
function toDB(img) {
  return ee.Image(img).log10().multiply(10.0);
}

//Apllying a Refined Lee Speckle filter as coded in the SNAP 3.0 S1TBX:

//https://github.com/senbox-org/s1tbx/blob/master/s1tbx-op-sar-processing/src/main/java/org/esa/s1tbx/sar/gpf/filtering/SpeckleFilters/RefinedLee.java
//Adapted by Guido Lemoine

// by Guido Lemoine
function RefinedLee(img) {
  // img must be in natural units, i.e. not in dB!
  // Set up 3x3 kernels 
  var weights3 = ee.List.repeat(ee.List.repeat(1,3),3);
  var kernel3 = ee.Kernel.fixed(3,3, weights3, 1, 1, false);

  var mean3 = img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), kernel3);
  var variance3 = img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), kernel3);

  // Use a sample of the 3x3 windows inside a 7x7 windows to determine gradients and directions
  var sample_weights = ee.List([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]);

  var sample_kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(7,7, sample_weights, 3,3, false);

  // Calculate mean and variance for the sampled windows and store as 9 bands
  var sample_mean = mean3.neighborhoodToBands(sample_kernel); 
  var sample_var = variance3.neighborhoodToBands(sample_kernel);

  // Determine the 4 gradients for the sampled windows
  var gradients = sample_mean.select(1).subtract(sample_mean.select(7)).abs();
  gradients = gradients.addBands(sample_mean.select(6).subtract(sample_mean.select(2)).abs());
  gradients = gradients.addBands(sample_mean.select(3).subtract(sample_mean.select(5)).abs());
  gradients = gradients.addBands(sample_mean.select(0).subtract(sample_mean.select(8)).abs());

  // And find the maximum gradient amongst gradient bands
  var max_gradient = gradients.reduce(ee.Reducer.max());

  // Create a mask for band pixels that are the maximum gradient
  var gradmask = gradients.eq(max_gradient);

  // duplicate gradmask bands: each gradient represents 2 directions
  gradmask = gradmask.addBands(gradmask);

  // Determine the 8 directions
  var directions = sample_mean.select(1).subtract(sample_mean.select(4)).gt(sample_mean.select(4).subtract(sample_mean.select(7))).multiply(1);
  directions = directions.addBands(sample_mean.select(6).subtract(sample_mean.select(4)).gt(sample_mean.select(4).subtract(sample_mean.select(2))).multiply(2));
  directions = directions.addBands(sample_mean.select(3).subtract(sample_mean.select(4)).gt(sample_mean.select(4).subtract(sample_mean.select(5))).multiply(3));
  directions = directions.addBands(sample_mean.select(0).subtract(sample_mean.select(4)).gt(sample_mean.select(4).subtract(sample_mean.select(8))).multiply(4));
  // The next 4 are the not() of the previous 4
  directions = directions.addBands(directions.select(0).not().multiply(5));
  directions = directions.addBands(directions.select(1).not().multiply(6));
  directions = directions.addBands(directions.select(2).not().multiply(7));
  directions = directions.addBands(directions.select(3).not().multiply(8));

  // Mask all values that are not 1-8
  directions = directions.updateMask(gradmask);

  // "collapse" the stack into a singe band image (due to masking, each pixel has just one value (1-8) in it's directional band, and is otherwise masked)
  directions = directions.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());  

  //var pal = ['ffffff','ff0000','ffff00', '00ff00', '00ffff', '0000ff', 'ff00ff', '000000'];
  //Map.addLayer(directions.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()), {min:1, max:8, palette: pal}, 'Directions', false);

  var sample_stats = sample_var.divide(sample_mean.multiply(sample_mean));

  // Calculate localNoiseVariance
  var sigmaV = sample_stats.toArray().arraySort().arraySlice(0,0,5).arrayReduce(ee.Reducer.mean(), [0]);

  // Set up the 7*7 kernels for directional statistics
  var rect_weights = ee.List.repeat(ee.List.repeat(0,7),3).cat(ee.List.repeat(ee.List.repeat(1,7),4));

  var diag_weights = ee.List([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,0,0,0,0], 
    [1,1,1,1,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,1,0,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]);

  var rect_kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(7,7, rect_weights, 3, 3, false);
  var diag_kernel = ee.Kernel.fixed(7,7, diag_weights, 3, 3, false);

  // Create stacks for mean and variance using the original kernels. Mask with relevant direction.
  var dir_mean = img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), rect_kernel).updateMask(directions.eq(1));
  var dir_var = img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), rect_kernel).updateMask(directions.eq(1));

  dir_mean = dir_mean.addBands(img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), diag_kernel).updateMask(directions.eq(2)));
  dir_var = dir_var.addBands(img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), diag_kernel).updateMask(directions.eq(2)));

  // and add the bands for rotated kernels
  for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    dir_mean = dir_mean.addBands(img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), rect_kernel.rotate(i)).updateMask(directions.eq(2*i+1)));
    dir_var = dir_var.addBands(img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), rect_kernel.rotate(i)).updateMask(directions.eq(2*i+1)));
    dir_mean = dir_mean.addBands(img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.mean(), diag_kernel.rotate(i)).updateMask(directions.eq(2*i+2)));
    dir_var = dir_var.addBands(img.reduceNeighborhood(ee.Reducer.variance(), diag_kernel.rotate(i)).updateMask(directions.eq(2*i+2)));
  }

  // "collapse" the stack into a single band image (due to masking, each pixel has just one value in it's directional band, and is otherwise masked)
  dir_mean = dir_mean.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
  dir_var = dir_var.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());

  // A finally generate the filtered value
  var varX = dir_var.subtract(dir_mean.multiply(dir_mean).multiply(sigmaV)).divide(sigmaV.add(1.0));

  var b = varX.divide(dir_var);

  var result = dir_mean.add(b.multiply(img.subtract(dir_mean)));
  return(result.arrayFlatten([['sum']]));
}

I tried to do some bias corrections on the threshold. Both relative and absolute corrections did not result in better results of the model.

Can you [edit] the question and reduce the code to a [mcve]? What do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].
